# How can I construct bitmap from Byte Array

Tags: blackberry

I need to read image from url then I have to set it as background of page ,so i need to construct Bitmap from byte array ,how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Bitmap Bytes2Bimap(byte[] b){  
            if(b.length!=0){  
                return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);  
            }  
            else {  
                return null;  
            }  
      }
```

Comment: I'm new to blackberry ..I tried your code but i could not find BitmapFactory class in any of blackberry packages !! Does it require some library ?? pls help ! Thanks

Comment: I'm not using Android SDK, here is the reference. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html, here is a relate post might help you: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Scaling-a-Bitmap-Without-EncodedImage/td-p/196460

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Howard .Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, byteArr.length);I want to achieve this in blackberry ,this line is for android .I have been unable to find a solution .The reference links you provided did not help.The first link refers to android. I'm still unable to use your code !

Answer (score 0):

Just import RIM library:

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
```

And use the function:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.length, 1);
```

Where `bytesArray` is your `byte[]` data